# How to list all collections and their objects?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I have a scene with 2 collections of 4 objects each. I am trying to get all collection names and their objects' names. Unfortunately, info panel nor python hints have not been helpful to find the command.

How do I get a list of all collections' names? How do I get a list of all objects' names in a given collection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access all collections through `bpy.data.collections`. The objects within the collection (and child collections) are given by `bpy.data.collections.all_objects`. This is documented in the [BlendData types](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.BlendData.html?highlight=collections#bpy.types.BlendData.collections) and the [documentation of the collection type](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Collection.html).

A little example script for printing the content of the collections:

```
import bpy

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
   print(collection.name)
   for obj in collection.all_objects:
      print("obj: ", obj.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Last two lines should have one indent less... I had an error for that but it was quickly fixed.

Comment: You're right. Fixed it.

Comment: BTW if you want to only have the objects within the collection, excluding child collections, you can use `bpy.data.collections.objects`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you, gtzkw!

Comment: how to get collections of a particular object?

Answer (score 10):

**Some python console code**

The python console is a great way to learn how the API works. For convenience `C = bpy.context` and `D = bpy.data`

Using simply the default file

[image]

All collections and all objects in each.

```
>>> for col in D.collections:
...     col.name, col.objects[:]
...     
('Collection 1', [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']])
```

or similarly

```
>>> for col in D.collections:
...     col.name
...     for o in col.objects:
...         o.name
...         
'Collection 1'
'Cube'
'Lamp'
'Camera'
```

Note the scene's top level or "master collection" is not listed above.

```
>>> C.scene.collection
bpy.data.collections['Master Collection']
```

Any objects in this collection?  No, but if we link objects to it `context.scene.collections.link(ob)`   there could be.

```
>>> C.scene.collection.objects[:]
[]
```

Worth mentioning the `all_objects` will recurse through and list all descendants (*children, grandchildren, ...*) collection's objects. In this case the child collection is "Collection 1"

```
>>> C.scene.collection.all_objects[:]
[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']]
```

Iterate through master collection's child collections, and list their objects.

```
>>> for col in C.scene.collection.children:
...     col.name, col.objects[:]
...     
('Collection 1', [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']])
```

Comment: Sorry batFINGER, your comment is very interesting and gives more knowledge than gtzkw's. However, he/she answered first and the answer solve my problem so I must give the point to that user. I am a new user and I do not have enough reputation to mark it as useful.
Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: aren't coll in D also potentially deleted "non-existent" collections?