# how can I select all objects in a collections using python?

Tags: python

I want to select all objects in a collection (collection names are known).

pseudo:

```
selectedObjs1 = allObjectsInCollectionName; <--- How?
for all objects in selectedObjs1:
    process...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process every object in a collection, you would have to iterate through [`Collection.all_objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection.all_objects):

```
collection = bpy.data.collections["collection_name"]
for obj in collection.all_objects:
    print(obj.name)
```

Further reading: [How to list all collections and their objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144928/how-to-list-all-collections-and-their-objects)

Comment: Yes you're right! I edited my post, thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot Tomreggae and Brockmann